# graphics not showing on internet but fine on localhost (php)

Tags: php, graphics

My favourite site and writing for the first time here. I have writing on an image using php this work fine on my localhost but it is not wortking on internet (000webhost) i have googled and then checked my gd library is on and i also set permissions to all but still the image is not showing.

```
<?php
session_start();
// File and new size
$filename = 'images/solar-kid.jpg';
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $txt=$_POST['txt'];
}

// Content type
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = 350;
$newheight = 300;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

$white = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, 399, 29, $black);
imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 270, 399, 299, $black);
$white = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 0, 0, 0);
$text = $txt;
$font = 'times.ttf';
imagettftext($thumb, 15, 0, 10, 20, $white, $font, $text);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);

?>
```

here is the result it showing on the site [Click here](http://haseeb.net63.net/write.php)

Answer (score 0):

000webhost free domain is not supporting i don`t know why. I uploaded it on another hosts paid server and it works like a charm